# Получение строки с максимальным значением

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица заказов `id, customerID, date, sum` как можно получить последний заказ каждого покупателя? Запрос с `GROUP BY(customerID)` с возможной последующей сортировкой по этим данным.

Comment: `id` инкремент? `date` задается пользователем при вводе заказа или является временем создания записи? Что будет считаться последним заказом запись с большим `id` или запись с более поздним значением `date`?

Comment: date это timestamp задается автоматически, последний заказ где date максимальное.

Comment: Какие поля вы хотите вернуть? Сами написать запрос пробовали?

Comment: я забыл указать есть еще поле суммы его и надо вернуть, писал запрос но смог получить только  дату последнего заказа через `MAX(date)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Базы данных на то и существуют, чтобы по сети минимум данных гонять и поддерживать целостность данных

такой составной запрос должен помочь вам

```
select t.id, t.customerID , t.date, t.sum
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select customerID, max(date) as MaxDate
    from MyTable
    group by customerID
) tm on t.customerID = tm.customerID and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.