# group by вместе с order by

Tags: mysql, group-by, order

Делается мультиязычность сайта путем вывода более популярных, собравших большее кол-во голосов, значений из mysql базы данных.

Таблица состоит:

```
|id|text_id|module|lang| text |voices|uid|
------------------------------------------
|1 |   1   |anketa| ru |Ашибка|   1  | 1 |
------------------------------------------
|2 |   1   |anketa| ru |Ошибка|   2  | 2 |
```

У меня получился запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM `langs` 
WHERE `module`='anketa' 
  AND `lang`='ru' 
GROUP BY `text_id` 
ORDER BY `voices` DESC
```

Но он выводит значение первое которое по списку с минимальным количеством `voices`, а должно выводить только с наибольшим количеством voices.

**Помогите составить правильный запрос.**

Comment: А что делать, если есть две записи с одинаковым text_id и равным максимальным voices?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь сначала с тем, что такое group by, а потом на основании этого решите, какая же именно информация о группе вам нужна https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-group-by-%D0%B2-mysql/599802#599802  возможно вам нужен order by max(voices). Но разумеется это даст только максимальное количество голосов, но не сами записи с таким количеством

Comment: Если будут 2 записи с одинаковым text_id и voices, тогда не критично что он выведет. Но один вариант должен уж точно выводить.

Comment: Mike, нужно как-то сгруппировать по `text_id`, а затем вывести только с наибольшими голосами варианты перевода

Comment: Что нибудь в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663590/194569 или другие ответы по теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%D1%81+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Mike, помогла первая ссылка, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение вопроса:

```
SELECT
    `l`.`text_id`, `l`.`text`, `l`.`voices`
FROM `langs` `l`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `text_id`, MAX(`voices`) AS `MaxVoice`
    FROM `langs`
    WHERE `module`='anketa' AND
    `lang`='ru'
    GROUP BY `text_id`
) `lm`
ON `l`.`text_id` = `lm`.`text_id` AND
   `l`.`voices` = `lm`.`MaxVoice` AND
   `l`.`module` = 'anketa' AND
   `l`.`lang` = 'ru'
GROUP BY `l`.`text_id`
ORDER BY `l`.`text_id` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае можно использовать такую штуку:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `langs` 
WHERE `module`='anketa' 
AND `lang`='ru' 
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM `langs` AS `langs_tmp` 
    WHERE `langs_tmp`.module=`langs`.module 
    AND `langs_tmp`.lang=`langs`.lang 
    AND `langs_tmp`.voices>`langs`.voices) 
GROUP BY `text_id` 
ORDER BY `voices` DESC
```

Таким способом, ты ставишь условие, что если есть поле выше по значению, то это не выведется. Примерно как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

По стандарту SQL в запросе с группировкой в части перечисления полей (то, что идет после SELECT) можно указывать ТОЛЬКО те поля, по которым идет группировка, или которые используются с групповыми функциями (sum, max, group_concat, ...). MySQL допускает выполнение запросов, не удовлетворяющих данному правилу. При этом для полей без групповых функций и не указанных в части GROUP BY выбирается произвольная строка из группы. Примеры см [Группировка в MySQL](https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Чел задал вопрос "я вот делаю так-то и у меня получается бяка, как мне сделать чтобы было норм?", Вы же отвечаете "да, если делать так-то, получится бяка".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(`voices`) AS `voices`, `id`
FROM `langs` 
WHERE `module`='anketa' 
  AND `lang`='ru' 
GROUP BY `text_id`
```

Comment: Это неверный ответ. В каких-то случаях он будет давать правильный результат, а в каких-то нет. Это чистый рандом. В поле `id` может вернуться значение не соответствующее `MAX(voices)`. В `SELECT` с группировкой безопасно подставлять только поля, по которым идет группировка и агрегирующие функции типа `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG`.