# Postgres игнорирует сортировку вывода по времени

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, select

Создаю материализованное представление в `PostgreSQL 11`. В котором нужно сделать выборку из нескольких таблиц: `publications`, `authors`, `tags` и `rubrics`. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, при выборке в новой таблице находятся все значения с данными 5-ти летней давности. А хотелось бы последние опубликованные. Может ли быть дело в агрегатных функциях или группировке?

p.s. Только что заметил, что и в столбце `typename` только одно значение, а их несколько. С чем это может быть связано? Как будет правильнее написать запрос?

p.p.s И столбец `rubricid` так же - только одно значение

Ниже прикладываю запрос:

```
create materialized view androidallpublications as
  SELECT publications.id,
    publications.publicationdate,
    publications.announceimgurl,
    publications.announce,
    publications.text,
    publications.sourcelink,
    publications.url,
    publications.commentcount,
    publicationstype.name as typename,
    rubrics.name as rubricname,
    rubrics.id as rubricid,
    authors.name as authorname,
    array_agg('{name : ' || tags.name || ' , id : ' || tags.id || '}') tags
  from publications
  inner join publicationstype on publications.pyblicationtypeid = publicationstype.id
  inner join rubrics on publications.rubricid = rubrics.id
  inner join authors on publications.authorid = authors.id
  inner join tagspublications on publications.id = tagspublications.pubid
  inner join tags on tagspublications.tagid = tags.id
  group by publications.id, publicationstype.name, rubrics.name, rubrics.id, authors.name
  order by publicationdate DESC
  limit 1000;
```

Минимально воспроизводимы пример:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.publications (
    title varchar NOT NULL,
    announce varchar NOT NULL,
    announceimgurl text NULL,
    "text" text NOT NULL,
    pyblicationtypeid int4 NULL,
    sourcelink varchar NULL,
    historyid int8 NULL,
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    publicationdate timestamp NOT NULL,
    updatedate timestamp NULL,
    rubricid int4 NULL,
    authorid int8 NULL,
    commentcount int4 NULL,
    url varchar NULL,
CONSTRAINT publications_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.publicationstype (
    "name" text NULL,
    id serial NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT publicationstype_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.rubrics (
    "name" text NULL,
    "subsCount" int4 NULL,
    "viewsCount" int4 NULL,
    id serial NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT rubrics_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE public.authors (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    email varchar NULL,
    "password" varchar NULL,
    "role" varchar NULL,
    confirmed bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT authors_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.tags (
    "views" int4 NOT NULL,
    "type" text NOT NULL,
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tags_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: *А хотелось бы последние опубликованные.* ну так измените порядок сортировки - сами же просите сперва самые старые...

Comment: `order by publicationdate ASC limit 1000;` Вы сортируете по возрастанию даты и берёте только 1000. Вместо ASC поставьте DESC :D

Comment: @AkinaПрошу прощения, не изменил перед вставкой. Изначально использовал DESC, позднее пытался посмотреть меняется ли вообще порядок сортировки, так ASC и осталось. При использовании DESC все равно публикации от 2014 года

Comment: @Kamushek Выше написал, извините

Comment: А какой тип у publicationdate? (на всякий случай)

Comment: @Kamushek timestamp

Comment: Полагаю, что вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774200/group-by-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-order-by) :D

Comment: В postgresql можно в `select` добавлять поля которых нет в `group by`? и в `order by` тоже можно их добавить? а как это должно работать?

Comment: @4per, нельзя. Никак не работает. Кроме functional dependency, т.е. группировки по уникальному ключу.

Comment: @Мелкий а почему у автора вопроса, тогда нет ошибки синтаксиса?

Comment: @4per ну это и не синтаксическая ошибка. А вообще ошибки вероятно нет как раз из-за обнаруженного functional dependency - если id это primary key соответствующих таблиц.

Comment: @Мелкий Разреши поинтересоваться, почему выводятся только определенные результаты? Или линку какую почитать посоветуешь? К сожалению, опыта в sql маловато

Comment: Соберите минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Мелкий такс и куда его?

Comment: В вопрос. Если не помещается - то попробуйте уменьшить.

Comment: @Мелкий Обновил вопрос, я правильно понял "минимально воспроизводимы пример"?

Comment: не хватает нескольких строк данных на которых будет видно некорректное поведение. И я уверен, что это - не минимальный пример. Попробуйте выбросить половину таблиц и две трети полей из оставшихся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря @Kamushek решил первый вопрос с сортировкой публикаций по времени.

```sql
select * from (
    select publications.id, 
        publications.publicationdate, 
        publications.announceimgurl, 
        publications.announce, 
        publications.text, 
        publications.sourcelink,
        publications.url,
        publications.commentcount,
        publicationstype.name as typename, 
        rubrics.name as rubricname, 
        rubrics.id as rubricid,
        authors.name as authorname,
        array_agg('{name : ' || tags.name || ' , id : ' || tags.id || '}') tags
    from publications 
    inner join publicationstype on publications.pyblicationtypeid = publicationstype.id
    inner join rubrics on publications.rubricid = rubrics.id
    inner join authors on publications.authorid = authors.id
    inner join tagspublications on publications.id = tagspublications.pubid
    inner join tags on tagspublications.tagid = tags.id
    group by publications.id, publicationstype.name, rubrics.name, rubrics.id, authors.name
    order by publicationdate desc
    ) as result
limit 1000;
```

Но оставшиеся вопросы еще актуальны. В столбце `typename`, `rubricID`, `rubricName` До сих фигурируют только одни значения. Я так понимаю дело в `group by`, который собсна и группирует результаты выборки. Причем не могу его не использовать, так как ругается, что там должны быть эти значения.

Таким образом, при выборке выводятся публикации только одного типа. Как это можно исправить?

P.s. При решении вопроса изменю его или опишу результат в коментах