# Работа с Базой данных. Вывод информации из БД

Tags: php, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста. В базу данных попадает информация о заказах, нужно из нее вывести данные о заказах которым больше 7 дней (это я сделал), а вот сложное если клиент в заказе повторяется (ID клиента), то чтобы выводился только последний по времени заказ, и выводился только если последний заказ старше 7 дней. Спасибо

Comment: А что за база данных ? В sql например что нибудь такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663590/194569 применимо. Хотя есть и более продвинутые способы в зависимости от конкретного диалекта sql.

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect(host,uzer,password,database). PHP Myadmyn. Примерно вот так подключаюсь, если я верно понял вопрос

Comment: ну значит у вас mysql. приведенный по ссылке запрос вполне рабочий на этой СУБД

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста - GROUP BY(customerID) - вот это что означает?

Comment: Выдает в результат по одной строке с каждым найденным cutomerID, для остальных полей вычисляются указанные агрегатные функции. В том примере берется максимальная дата для каждого customerID. Подробнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: В примере после select идет перебор столбцов с приписанной t, а если у меня все столбцы и указано SELECT * FROM action_items, верно ли будет вот такое написание SELECT t * FROM action_items (скорее всего нет), а как верно написать?

Comment: там таблице дан алиас `from MyTable t` после этого к этому экземпляру таблицы в запросе можно обращаться по имени t. в том числе и как `t.*`

Answer (score 0):

В итоге вот так сделал, спасибо за подсказки
'''SELECT t.*  FROM `action`t inner join( select phone, date, max(date) as MaxDate from action group by phone) tm on t.phone = tm.phone and t.date = tm.MaxDate'''